# How to change colors and band labels in Data Explorer's plot_missing() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

If anyone else has tried to customize the colors and hard-code the band labels in `DataExplorer`'s `plot_missing()` function, here is an easy way to do so.

**Default Output**

```
# To show all bands I've replaced `species` column in the `starwars` dataset with NA
data(starwars)
df <- starwars
df$species <- NA

library(DataExplorer)
plot_missing(df)
```

[image]

As you can see, the resulting figure has the band labels in alphabetical order "Bad, Good, OK, Remove", which doesn't work too well with coordinating colors. E.g. "Remove" color is purple when it makes most sense to be red (due to `ggplot2`'s default colors being used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the output `plot_missing` figure more legible, you can change the root function of `plot_missing()` and assign it to another variable (`plot_missing_2`).

```
# Original function
function (data, group = list(Good = 0.05, OK = 0.4, Bad = 0.8, 
  Remove = 1), geom_label_args = list(), title = NULL, ggtheme = theme_gray(), 
theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))) 
{
  pct_missing <- Band <- NULL
  missing_value <- data.table(profile_missing(data))
  group <- group[sort.list(unlist(group))]
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(group), function(i) {
    if (i == 1) {
      missing_value[pct_missing <= group[[i]], `:=`(Band, 
        names(group)[i])]
    } else {
      missing_value[pct_missing > group[[i - 1]] & pct_missing <= 
         group[[i]], `:=`(Band, names(group)[i])]
    }
}))
  output <- ggplot(missing_value, aes_string(x = "feature", 
    y = "num_missing", fill = "Band")) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_discrete("Band") + coord_flip() + xlab("Features") + 
    ylab("Missing Rows")
  geom_label_args_list <- list(mapping = aes(label = paste0(round(100 * 
    pct_missing, 2), "%")))
  output <- output + do.call("geom_label", c(geom_label_args_list, 
    geom_label_args))
  class(output) <- c("single", class(output))
  plotDataExplorer(plot_obj = output, title = title, ggtheme = ggtheme, 
    theme_config = theme_config)
}
```

Mainly, change `group = list(Good = 0.05, OK = 0.4, Bad = 0.8, Remove = 1)` to `group = list(Good = 0.05, Okay = 0.4, Poor = 0.8, Scarce = 1)` and `scale_fill_discrete("Band")` to `scale_fill_manual("Band", values = c("Good"="green2","Okay"="gold","Poor"="darkorange","Scarce"="firebrick2"))`. You can set your own groups to your liking, just remember the order the bands are displayed are in alphabetical order (haven't tinkered with that yet). You can also change the colors to whatever you prefer as well. Just remember to assign the `plot_missing()` function to a new variable e.g. `plot_missing_2`.

**Customized Function**

```
# Custom function
plot_missing_2 <-
function (data, group = list(Good = 0.05, Okay = 0.4, Poor = 0.8, 
  Scarce =  1), geom_label_args = list(), title = NULL, ggtheme = theme_gray(), 
theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))) 
{
  pct_missing <- Band <- NULL
  missing_value <- data.table(profile_missing(data))
  group <- group[sort.list(unlist(group))]
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(group), function(i) {
    if (i == 1) {
      missing_value[pct_missing <= group[[i]], `:=`(Band,
         names(group)[i])]
    } else {
  missing_value[pct_missing > group[[i - 1]] & pct_missing <= 
     group[[i]], `:=`(Band, names(group)[i])]
    }
}))
  output <- ggplot(missing_value, aes_string(x = "feature", 
    y = "num_missing", fill = "Band")) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
   scale_fill_manual("Band", values = c("Good"="green2","Okay"="gold","Poor"="darkorange","Scarce"="firebrick2")) + coord_flip() + xlab("Features") + 
   ylab("Missing Rows")
  geom_label_args_list <- list(mapping = aes(label = paste0(round(100 * 
    pct_missing, 2), "%")))
  output <- output + do.call("geom_label", c(geom_label_args_list, 
     geom_label_args))
  class(output) <- c("single", class(output))
  plotDataExplorer(plot_obj = output, title = title, ggtheme = ggtheme, 
   theme_config = theme_config)
}
```

**Customized Output**

```
data(starwars)
df <- starwars
df$species <- NA  

library(DataExplorer)  
plot_missing_2(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Big thanks to @Boxuan for the helpful hints and quick response time!